# Bittrex API - delay in candle (OHLC) data

Tags: rest, api

(originally asked in [bitcoin.stackexchange](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/70272/bittrex-api-3-minute-delay) but didn't get much traction there ... )

I'm noticing that the Bittrex API (both v1.1 and v2.0) have a 3 to 4 minute delay when getting data, i.e. GetLatestTick: https://bittrex.com/api/v2.0/pub/market/GetLatestTick?marketName=BTC-NEO&tickInterval=hour

So if you make a request say at 8:00PM, it will not bring the 7:00 to 8:00PM candle (OHLC) data until 8:03PM, some times 8:04PM ...

I thought about constructing my own candles querying the API every few seconds with /getticker - but for a few cryptos it will get lengthy and might get banned for the amount of requests per second ...

Contacted Bittrex, but never had a response back.

Anyone knows any other method to get candle data sooner?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ClueDex](https://www.cluedex.com/product/api/ohlcv-candle-api) is what I'm using to get up to the second candle OHLCV data. They claim to be between 2 and four minutes faster than the Bittrex API. That matters a lot when you're trying to integrate the data into a trading platform or create a high frequency trading bot, particularly with the Parabolic SAR metric, which is a high confidence trading signal.

Answer (score 1):

Try Enigmas Catalyst - you get minute data from Bitfinex, Bittrex and Poloniex for backtesting and livetrading

https://enigma.co/